# How to Promise.all with redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, promise, redux-toolkit

I have the code that present button to submit upload image and upload profile. This to function that use seperate api and when I use the promise.all to wait for both api set status 200 then click submit, but not working. The image upload still fetch api even the upload profile fail with status 400

This is my code in slice.j

```
export const updateUser = createAsyncThunk('superadmin/updateProfile', async (payload) => {
    try {
        const response = await updateProfile({
            email: payload.email,
            fullname: payload.fullname,
            dob: payload.dob,
            gender: payload.gender,
            phoneNumber: payload.phoneNumber,
        });
        if (response.statusCode === 200) {
            return response; // return the response data if status is 200
        } else {
            throw new Error('Response status is not 200');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});

export const updateCurrentUserAvatar = createAsyncThunk('superadmin/updateAvatar', async (data) => {
    try {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', data);
        const response = await axios.post('User/avatar', formData);
        if (response.statusCode === 200) {
            return response; // return the response data if status is 200
        } else {
            throw new Error('Response status is not 200');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});

extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder
            .addCase(getAdminData.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                state.data = action.payload.data;
                state.count = action.payload.count;
            })
            .addCase(updateAdminStatus.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                state.adminId = action.payload.adminId;
                state.isLocked = action.payload.isLocked;
            })
            .addCase(createAdmin.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                state.admins.push(action.payload);
            })
            .addCase(getCurrentUserAvatar.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                state.avatar = action.payload;
            })
            .addCase(updateCurrentUserAvatar.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                state.avatar = action.payload;
            })
            .addCase(updateUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                state.update.push(action.payload);
            });
    },
});
```

Here where I dispatch action and submit button

```
 const onSubmit = (data) => {
        setFormData({
            email: data.email,
            fullname: data.fullname,
            dob: convertDateFormat(data.dob),
            gender: data.gender,
            phoneNumber: data.phoneNumber,
        });
    };
 const handleUpdate = async () => {
        const promise1 = dispatch(updateCurrentUserAvatar(updateImage));
        const promise2 = dispatch(updateUser(formData));
        try {
            const [result1, result2] = await Promise.all([promise1, promise2]);
            if (result1.statusCode === 200 && result2.statusCode === 200) {
                dispatch(updateCurrentUserAvatar.fulfilled(result1.payload));
                dispatch(updateUser.fulfilled(result2.payload));
            } else {
                throw new Error('Response status is not 200');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className={cx('wrapper')}>
            <h2 className={cx('text_wrapper')}>Thông tin tài khoản</h2>

            <div className={cx('container')}>
                <div className={cx('left_container')}>
                    {loading ? (
                        <Spinner />
                    ) : (
                        <>
                            <img src={imageProfile} alt="" style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }} />
                            <input id="upload" type="file" accept="image/*" hidden />
                            <label className={cx('change_image')} htmlFor="upload" onClick={handleButtonClick}>
                                Change Image
                            </label>
                        </>
                    )}
                    {/* <button type="submit" onClick={handleUpload}>
                        Cập nhật ảnh đại diện
                    </button> */}
                    <div>{currentUser.email}</div>
                </div>

                <div className={cx('right_container')}>
                    <form id={cx('update_form')} onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                        <label>Họ và Tên</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Nhập Họ và Tên" {...register('fullname')} />
                        <label>Địa chỉ email</label>
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Nhập địa chỉ email" {...register('email')} />
                        <label>Ngày sinh</label>
                        <input type="date" {...register('dob')} />
                        <select defaultValue="" {...register('gender', { required: true })}>
                            <option value="" disabled>
                                Chọn giới tính
                            </option>
                            <option value="Male">Male</option>
                            <option value="Female">Female</option>
                            <option value="Other">Other</option>
                        </select>
                        <label>Số điện thoại</label>
                        <input type="tel" placeholder="Nhập số điện thoại" {...register('phoneNumber')} />

                        <button
                            type="submit"
                            id={cx('submit_btn')}
                            className={cx('align-center')}
                            onClick={() => setOpen(true)}
                        >
                            Cập nhật thông tin cá nhân
                        </button>
                        <div className={cx('modal_container')}>
                            {open && (
                                <Modal show={open} onClose={() => setOpen(false)}>
                                    <h2>Bạn đồng ý cập nhật thông tin cá nhân ? </h2>
                                    <div className={cx('container_confirm')}>
                                        <button className={cx('button_active')} onClick={handleUpdate}>
                                            <BsCheckLg className={cx('icon_modal')} />
                                            Đồng ý
                                        </button>
                                        <button className={cx('button_lock')} onClick={() => setOpen(false)}>
                                            <HiOutlineXMark className={cx('icon_modal')} />
                                            Huỷ bỏ
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </Modal>
                            )}
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a lot of work here manually which you don't need to be doing!

```
dispatch(updateUser.fulfilled(result2.payload));
```

You don't need to individually dispatch the `updateUser.fulfilled` or `updateUser.rejected` actions.  The thunk will handle that internally.

```
export const updateUser = createAsyncThunk('superadmin/updateProfile', async (payload) => {
    try {
        const response = await updateProfile({
            email: payload.email,
            fullname: payload.fullname,
            dob: payload.dob,
            gender: payload.gender,
            phoneNumber: payload.phoneNumber,
        });
        if (response.statusCode === 200) {
            return response; // return the response data if status is 200
        } else {
            throw new Error('Response status is not 200');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

You also don't want to `catch` errors in the thunk.  When you do this, it causes the `updateUser.fulfilled` action to get dispatched by the thunk instead of `updateUser.rejected`.  If you `throw` an error and don't `catch` it then Redux Toolkit will handle this by dispatching the `updateUser.rejected` action.

`axios` should actually [`throw` some errors of its own](https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors), so I think you don't even need to check the status code?

Try this:

```
export const updateUser = createAsyncThunk('superadmin/updateProfile', async (payload) => {
        const response = await updateProfile({
            email: payload.email,
            fullname: payload.fullname,
            dob: payload.dob,
            gender: payload.gender,
            phoneNumber: payload.phoneNumber,
        });
        return response;
});

export const updateCurrentUserAvatar = createAsyncThunk('superadmin/updateAvatar', async (data) => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', data);
        const response = await axios.post('User/avatar', formData);
        return response;
});
```

```
const handleUpdate = async () => {
    dispatch(updateUser(formData));
    dispatch(updateCurrentUserAvatar(updateImage));
}
```

It sounds like possibly you only want to execute `updateCurrentUserAvatar` if `updateUser` succeeds?  This might not be exactly what you want, but it should be an improvement.

Comment: yeah i try to do it but the api changed avatar always fetch first and return 200 status which mean it auto changed avatar without dispatch action. So it do it with 2 button instead.